# How do I implement a flagging functionality which displays icon next to an item in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want the add the ability to flag responses to a question in a web app? There would be "flag this response" next to each response. When the div is clicked an "X"  icon (indicating its flagged) is placed next to the response and the div now says "Unflag this response". To remove the flag, click the div again (a toggle effect).

Is there widget that already exist that works for mvc? How do I get started?

Comment: Chaka, the question is a bit vague. Are you asking how to create an Ajax call to update db and DOM?

Comment: I was looking how to implement it on the view..would it just be adding a click event to the div (via Jquery) and Ajax call to update the flag on db? Any code snippet would be appreciated?